# Getting a p-value of 0 on a normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, python, data-visualization, p-value

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

wine = pd.read_csv('red wine quality.csv')
wine = wine.dropna()
wine_density = wine[['density']] # Isolating column 'density'
wine_density = wine_density.squeeze() # Reformating as pd.Series
wine_density = pd.to_numeric(wine_density) # Converting from Str to numeric
from scipy import stats
stat, p1 = stats.shapiro(wine_density)
print('Statistics = {0:.3f}, p = {1:.3f}'.format(stat, p1))
alpha = 0.05
if p1 > alpha:
    print('Fail to reject H0, sample is normal.')
else:
    print('Reject H0, sample is NOT normal.)')
```

When I run this code, I get:

```
runcell(9, 'C:/Users/Adam/Desktop/DSCI 200/Week 8/Week8_Final_Project.py')
Statistics = 0.991, p = 0.000
Reject H0, sample is NOT normal.)
```

However, when I run graphical normality tests such as the qqtest or a histogram, respectively, I get:

```
from statsmodels.graphics.gofplots import qqplot
qqplot(wine_density, line = 's')
plt.show()
Normality qqtest
```

[image: Normality qqtest]

and

```
plt.hist(wine_density, bins=50)
plt.show()
Normality histogram
```

[image: Normality histogram]

Both images look like normal distribution to me, but even if they aren't, getting a p value of absolute zero seems erroneous. What am I misunderstanding and/or doing wrong?

Here is my original data set - https://www.kaggle.com/uciml/red-wine-quality-cortez-et-al-2009?select=winequality-red.csv

Comment: You have a dataset that is so large, even tiny deviations from Normality are significant.  The histogram departs visibly from Normality and the probability plot clarifies how and to what extent the data are non-Normal.  Thus, everything fits and nothing is strange.

Comment: This only makes sense because I just got done reading your "A Dialog between a Teacher and a Thoughtful Student" answer to another question, so thank you for both! In other words, then, I did the test correctly. The set is NOT normal, but graphically appears to be so due to it's size. A p-value 0.000 is expected, then?

Comment: The p-value isn't zero. It's just very, very small.

Comment: @Robert Long, I see. When I reset my alpha value to 0.0000001, null is still rejected. When I add a zero and make it 0.00000001, I finally fail to reject null. So it's just a matter of setting an amazingly specific alpha.

Comment: Yes, although the practice of adjusting the level of significance according to whether you want to reject or fail to reject the null hypothesis is not recommended.  What is your reason for testing normality, by the way ?

Comment: School project. I'm a non-traditional student. So no real reason other than that I am trying to better understand how the process works. Although I am gathering that, at least on some level, whether or not data are normal is a matter is somewhat a matter of opinion.